# How to quickly remove a pair of parentheses, brackets, or braces in Vim?

Tags: vim

In Vim, if I have code (in Ruby) like so:

```
anArray << [anElement]
```

and my cursor is on the first `[`, I can hop to `]` with the `%` key, and I can delete all the content between the `[]` pair with `d%`.

But what if I just want to delete the `[` and `]` leaving all the remaining content between the two? In other words, what is the quickest way to get to:

```
anArray << anElement
```

Comment: I would do `xf]`, but it doesn't do paren-matching.  Or, first do a manual paren-matching by `%`, then `x` followed by two backticks, followed by `x`.

Comment: excellent question. I'm a prolific vim user, and this does come up from time to time, and I have no good built-in solution.

Comment: Alok's second option works a treat.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Using the [Surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin for Vim, you can eliminate surrounding delimiters with `ds<delimeter>`.

To install it via [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) plugin, add

```
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
```

to your `.vimrc` file and run `:PluginInstall`.

Answer (score 101):

One can take advantage of the text objects that are built in into Vim
(see `:help text-objects`). The desired edit can be stated as a
sequence of the following three actions.

1. Cut the text inside the square brackets:

   ```
    di[
   ```
2. Select the (empty) square brackets:

   ```
    va[
   ```

   Alternatively, you can just select the character under the
   cursor and the one to the left of it, because the command
   from step 1 always puts the cursor on the closing bracket:

   ```
    vh
   ```
3. Paste the cut text over the selected brackets:

   ```
    p
   ```

Altogether, it gives us the following sequence of Normal-mode commands:

```
di[va[p
```

or, when the alternative form of step 2 is used:

```
di[vhp
```

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating a non-plugin way to do this! Great for those of us working on embedded systems.

Comment: Can't you just just skip the first step? `va[` will select the brackets and everything inside them. Then `p` will paste over the whole thing. I'm not sure what `di[` does here. I know I'm responding to an old answer, so maybe it didn't used to work this way?

Comment: @JonathanWren: If you do just `va[p`, you would end up with the content of the unnamed register—whatever it is at that moment—overwriting the bracketed text; `di[` is necessary to first cut the text within brackets into that register for the following `va[p` to overwrite with.

Answer (score 80):

`` ma%x`ax `` (mark position in register `a`, go to matching paren, delete char, go to mark `a`, delete char).

EDIT:

``` %x``x ``` does the same thing ([thanks to @Alok for the tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084210/remove-a-pair-of-parentheses-brackets-or-braces-in-vim/14387789#comment2015984_2084221)).

Comment: As I said in my main comment, you don't need a manual mark: you can go to the last position by two backticks.  So  %x``x is faster.

Comment: This is similar to what I've been doing, but it's an awful lot of key-presses for an editor that's supposed to be very key-press-efficient.

Comment: I like `%%x``x` better since you can be anywhere inside the parens.

Comment: You can only execute `%%x\`\`x` and get the desired effect inside parens which do not have nested parens though.

Comment: `%x ctrl-o x` also works for those a little more used to that jump-back shortcut.

Answer (score 11):

If you have issues with the marks pointing to the first char of the line or with using % ...

```
di[vhp
```

works as well... It deletes matching [] brackets, when the cursor is anywhere inside. '[' can be replaced by '{' or '(' .

Answer (score 5):

The other answers work fine if you want to delete delimiters one line at a time.

If on the other hand you want to remove a function and it's delimiters from the entire file use:

```
:%s/function(\(.*\))/\1/g
```

which replaces `function(arguments)` with `arguments` everywhere in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use d% while your cursor is on the bracket/parentheses.

Comment: this does not remove only the brackets, but the brackets including the text in between.