# In Vim, is there a "matching braces/parenthesis/etc" equivalent in substitute/search symbols?

Tags: regex, vim

I would like to replace for instance every occurrence of "foo{...}" with anything except newlines inside the bracket (there may be spaces, other brackets opened AND closed, etc) NOT followed by "bar".

For instance, the "foo{{  }}" in "foo{{  }}, bar" would match but not "foo{hello{}}bar".

I've tried `/foo{.*}\(bar\)\@!` and `/foo{.\{-}}\(bar\)\@!` but the first one would match "foo{}bar{}" and the second would match "foo{{}}bar" (only the "foo{{}" part).

Comment: Not sure how this will translate to `vim`, but you can look at [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/uZ4vN8/1). It uses negative look-ahead and I don't think you can do that in `vim`, but hopefully it sets you on the right track

Comment: Vim *does* have negative look-ahead, using the `\@!` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

this regex:

```
foo{.*}\([}]*bar\)\@!
```

matches:

```
foo{{ }}
foo{{ }}, bar
```

but not:

```
foo{hello{}}bar
```

Comment: thank you, but this would match the `foo{hello{}` in `foo{hello{}goodbye}bar`, wouldn't it ?
Actually this is reminding me some discussion on formal languages with a friend, who told me something like "you cannot determine if a set of parenthesis is correct with a regex". This would make my problem unsolvable...

Comment: Yes, your friend is correct. It is impossible to correctly match an arbitrary level of nested parentheses using regular expressions. However, it is possible to construct a regex to match supporting a limited amount of nesting (I think this answer did not attempt to do so).

Comment: Well, that would be great as I don't think there will be more than two or three couples of brackets inside.

Answer (score 0):

> It is impossible to correctly match an arbitrary level of nested
>   parentheses using regular expressions. However, it is possible to
>   construct a regex to match supporting a limited amount of nesting (I
>   think this answer did not attempt to do so). –  Ben

This does ...

for up to one level of inner braces:

```
/foo{[^{}]*\({[^{}]*}[^{}]*\)*}\(bar\)\@!
```

for up to two levels of inner braces:

```
/foo{[^{}]*\({[^{}]*\({[^{}]*}[^{}]*\)*}[^{}]*\)*}\(bar\)\@!
```

for up to three levels of inner braces:

```
/foo{[^{}]*\({[^{}]*\({[^{}]*\({[^{}]*}[^{}]*\)*}[^{}]*\)*}[^{}]*\)*}\(bar\)\@!
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what replacement you want to perform exactly, you might be able to do that with macros.

For example: Given this text

```
line 1 -- -- -- -- array[a][b[1]]
line 2 -- array[c][d]
line 3 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- array[e[0]][f] + array[g[0]][h[0]]
```

replace `array[A][B]` with `get(A, B)`.

To do that:

- Position the cursor at the begin of the text
- `/array<cr>`
- `qq` to begin recording a macro
- Do something to change the data independent of the content inside (use `%` to go to matching bracket, and [some register/mark/plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2084210/5267751) to delete around the bracket). For example `cwget(<esc>ldi[vhpa, <esc>ldi[vhpa)<esc>n` -- but macros are usually unreadable.
- `n` to go to next match, `q` to stop recording
- `@q` repeatedly (`@@` can be used from the second time)

This is probably not very convenient because it's easy to make a mistake (press `I`, `<home>`, `A` for example) and you have to redo the macro from the beginning, but it works.

Alternatively, you can do something similar to `eregex.vim` plugin to extend vim's regex format to support this (so you don't have to retype the huge regex every time).

Proof of concept:

```
"does not handle different magic levels
"does not handle '\/' or different characters for substitution ('s#a#b#')
"does not handle brackets inside strings


" usage: `:M/pattern, use \zm for matching block/replacement/flags`

command -range -nargs=* M :call SubstituteWithMatching(<q-args>, <line1>, <line2>)
":M/ inspired from eregex.vim

function SubstituteWithMatching(command, line1, line2)
    let EscapeRegex={pattern->escape(pattern, '[]\')}
    let openbracket ='([{'
    let closebracket=')]}'
    let nonbracketR='[^'.EscapeRegex(openbracket.closebracket).']'
    let nonbracketsR=nonbracketR.'*'


    let LiftLevel={pattern->
                \nonbracketsR
                \.'\%('
                \.'['.EscapeRegex(openbracket).']'
                \.pattern
                \.'['.EscapeRegex(closebracket).']'
                \.nonbracketsR
                \.'\)*'
                \}

    let matchingR=LiftLevel(LiftLevel(LiftLevel(nonbracketsR)))

    if v:false " optional test suite
        echo "return 0:"
        echo match('abc', '^'.matchingR.'$')
        echo match('abc(ab)de', '^'.matchingR.'$')
        echo match('abc(ab)d(e)f', '^'.matchingR.'$')
        echo match('abc(a[x]b)d(e)f', '^'.matchingR.'$')
        echo match('abc(a]b', '^'.matchingR.'$')
        "current flaw (not a problem if there's only one type of bracket, or if
        "the code is well-formed)

        echo "return -1:"
        echo match('abc(a(b', '^'.matchingR.'$')
        echo match('abc)a(b', '^'.matchingR.'$')
    endif

    let [pattern, replacement, flags]=split(a:command, "/")
    let pattern=substitute(pattern, '\\zm', EscapeRegex(matchingR), 'g')
    execute a:line1.','.a:line2.'s/'.pattern.'/'.replacement.'/'.flags
endfunction
```

After this, `:'<,'>M/array\[\(\zm\)\]\[\(\zm\)\]/get(\1, \2)/g` can be used to do the same task above (after selecting the text in visual mode)