# VIm change bracket types (without using search and replace)

Tags: vim

I am looking for a VIM key combo for changing something like

```
blahblah["hello"]
```

to

```
blahblah("hello")
```

My best effort so far is

```
0f[yi[%c%()^["0P^[
```

but anything better would be much appreciated.

BTW, my combo works by doing:

1. find the first instance of `[` (you get my point),
2. yank the insides (which of course means to register 0 by default, and it leaves the cursor on the first `"`),
3. move the cursor back onto the first instance of `[` with `%`,
4. delete the whole `[...]` bit and go into insert mode,
5. write `()` and `<Esc>` out of insert mode,
6. paste the contents of register 0 in between the `()`.

Comment: I think this may do what you want (never used it myself): http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script%5Fid=1697

Comment: Would a simple search/replace not work?  i.e. substitute all `[` for `(`?

Comment: Why not search/replace:  `:s/[/(/g` & `:s/]/)/g` ?

Comment: Yes I could of course do a search and replace, but this is the sort of thing that I was hoping I could have a combo that I throw at it sort-of 'inline', if you get my drift. You know, something that just feels right.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker. Yes that script you suggest looks the business, but surely this is the sort of thing that would be good to have in the muscle memory for a vanilla VIM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping to have a muscle-memorable key combination that I could use for things like this where you want to 'keep the contents but change the surroundings'.

My proposal, if you reduce it to the minimum (and use `ca[` rather than `%c%` -- credit to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14387789/1243435) for the `a` motion that I had not really known about) is not too bad because it is the sort of thing you can invent again once you know it is possible:

```
yi[ca[()<Esc>"0P
```

However, it occurred to me that a search-and-replace is going to be just the right kind of solution when you need to do a few of these in a file. Here is my best effort:

1. select the area in visual mode (I tend to use `VISUAL LINE` mode as a default),
2. then `:s/\[\(.\{-}\)\]/(\1)/g<Enter>` and you're done.

That itself looks a bit mad, but it is just a simple example of so-called *backreferencing* so I was quite happy to have had to get that clear in my mind too.